# Docker Error: System.InvalidOperationException:

Tags: docker

I installed docker and ran it, it was ok. but after a restart i have this problem:
System.InvalidOperationException:
job failed with message: 'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID 4160C5EC-02BD-46FA-99E3-3B99203D966A)

'DockerDesktopVM' Synthetic SCSI Controller (Instance ID 7DF00258-64CD-42EE-9C46-40C402778132): Failed to Power on with Error 'The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.' (0x80070570). (Virtual machine ID 4160C5EC-02BD-46FA-99E3-3B99203D966A)

'DockerDesktopVM': Attachment 'F:\Docker_data\DockerDesktop\DockerDesktop.vhdx' failed to open because of error: 'The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.' (0x80070570). (Virtual machine ID 4160C5EC-02BD-46FA-99E3-3B99203D966A)
at Docker.Backend.HyperVInfrastructure.HandleUpdatedJob(CIMConcreteJob updatedJob) in C:\workspaces\PR-18003\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperVInfrastructure.cs:line 772
at Docker.Backend.HyperVInfrastructure.d__40.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-18003\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperVInfrastructure.cs:line 706
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Docker.Backend.HyperVInfrastructure.d__32.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-18003\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperVInfrastructure.cs:line 554
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Docker.Backend.HyperV.d__6.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-18003\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperV.cs:line 105
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Docker.Backend.HttpAPI.HyperVController.d__7.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-18003\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HttpAPI\HyperVController.cs:line 49
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()

I reinstalled docker and again in first it was ok but after restart the problem reappeared.
My windows is serever 2019.
when i delete DockerDesktop.vhdx file, docker will run.